# Left/right rotation of BST infinite loop between two unsatisfactory solutions?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I don't know my algorithms too well, so I'm probably missing something really basic. It seems to me that a standard rotate-left/rotate-right implementation (I'm looking at [this link](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/balanced.html) from Interactive Python) on this tree (called any time the balancing factor is not -1, 0, 1) will get into an infinite loop because the balancing factor will always be -2 or +2. Am I missing something or is this the correct conclusion? I'm pasting sample code at the bottom showing `rotateLeft` as implemented in the link I pasted

[image: trees]

```
def rotateLeft(self,rotRoot):
    newRoot = rotRoot.rightChild
    rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild
    if newRoot.leftChild != None:
        newRoot.leftChild.parent = rotRoot
    newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
    if rotRoot.isRoot():
        self.root = newRoot
    else:
        if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
                rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
        else:
            rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
    newRoot.leftChild = rotRoot
    rotRoot.parent = newRoot
    rotRoot.balanceFactor = rotRoot.balanceFactor + 1 - min(newRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
    newRoot.balanceFactor = newRoot.balanceFactor + 1 + max(rotRoot.balanceFactor, 0)
```

Does this avoid an infinite loop (with its complementary `rotateRight`), and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of balancing BST's is that you not only have a left/right rotate, but instead you have 4 types of shifts. A left,left rotate (similar to right right), and a right-left rotate(similar to left-right). 
I may be wrong at least this is the algorithm I had to write. Where the directions of left and right represent where you traveled the last 2 steps of the tree to find your insertion point.
You may want to look into AVL tree's as this seems like the type of problem you are trying to solve.